# How to enable endpoint to filter the result based on all the available fields in fastAPI?

Tags: python, fastapi

I'm trying to enable filtering for a set of json result through my endpoints. The filter should be optional, can be added directly through the endpoints as (url/?postId=1&...)
I'm utilizing fastAPI in Python for the study. Here's what I've got so far.

Router

```
@router.get('/comments',
            summary="Fetch all comments",
            status_code=200,
            response_model=List[Comments],
            response_description="Returns comments data."
            )
def fetch_all_comments(
    postId: Optional[str] = None,
    id: Optional[int] = None,
    name: Optional[str] = None,
    email: Optional[str] = None,
    body: Optional[str] = None
):

    # FETCHING DATA FROM JSON PLACEHOLDER
    result = jsonplaceholder.fetch_comments()

    for attr in [x for x in result if result[x] is not None]:
        query = query.filter(getattr(Comments, attr).like(result[attr]))

    return query
```

Dependencies

```
def fetch_comments():
    # FIRE REQUEST TO GET ALL COMMENTS
    req = requests.get(
        "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/comments", verify=False)

    # HANDLING ERRORS WITHIN THIRD PARTY REQUEST
    if req.status_code not in [200, 201]:
        raise ThirdPartyException(
            "Error", req.status_code, req.reason)

    # PREPARING THE PAYLOAD FOR THE RESPONSE
    response = req.json()

    return response
```

Models

```
class Comments(BaseModel):
    postId: str
    id: int
    name: str
    email: str
    body: str
```

I feel like the error is on the router side, in which running the application will provide me with an error of 'for attr in [x for x in result if result[x] is not None]:
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not dict'

currently, return result will give me all the comments, without any filter. My end result that I'm hoping to get is '/comments?postId=1' will return me with only the json result with 'postId=1' and 'comments?postId=1&id=2' will return result based on respective filters 'postId=1&id=2'.

May I get any recommendation on the fix that should've been made? thanks for any suggestion and help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay this is how I solve on getting APIs to return all filtered field as the result.

```
    kwargs = '{}'
    j = json.loads(kwargs)

    if postId:
        j.update({"postId": postId})
    if id:
        j.update({"id": id})
    if name:
        j.update({"name": name})
    if email:
        j.update({"email": email})
    if body:
        j.update({"body": body})

    arguments = [x for x in j.keys() if x]
    result = jsonplaceholder.fetch_comments()
    empty = []
    for y in arguments:
        empty = filter_comments(
            {'key': y, 'value': j[y]}, empty if empty else result)
    print(j)
    return empty
```

There should be a better way to iterate through all the field instead of just listing it in an if statements, however due to my lack of logical thinking decided to solve it this way. Please edit the answer if you guys are able to help reformat it in a better way. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

have you tried filter like this:

```
from sqlalchemy import and_,or_,not_
query(Comments).filter(and_(Comments.name.like(name),Comments.email.like(email), ....)
```

Comment: I dont use sqlalchemy for this backend application